# Display viewable <div> as counter

Tags: jquery, carousel, counter

I have a carousel of divs and need to display a 'counter' of sorts - I can display the number of visible divs easily enough, but I want to display those visible as:

1-4 of 12

Using jQuery cycle, HTML is:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="carousel1">
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
</div>

<div id="carousel2">
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
</div>

<div id="carousel3">
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

As you can see, I have 3 carousel panels... but how do I use jQuery to count the number of divs inside each panel and also the total number of these divs so that the counter displays as:

1-4 of 12

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#wrapper [id^=carousel]").children().length; // total no of children inside carousel
$("#wrapper [id^=carousel]").length; // total carousel
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4wqb20v/6/)**

Comment: Sorry yes, it just returns an alert of total divs - it doesn't display the output as requested

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use jquery [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and save each container child in an array:

```js
//the selector is every div with id starts with carousel
//that is ancestor of an element with id wrapper
var childLen = $("#wrapper div[id^='carousel']").map(function() {
  return $(this).children().length;
}).get();
//outputs  [4, 4, 4]
console.log(childLen);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="carousel1">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>
  <div id="carousel2">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>
  <div id="carousel3">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**References**

[**.children()**](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Sorry, have now added a new div for where the "1-4 of 12" output is to be displayed.. can't get your code to output anything unfortunately

Comment: You can use an object and keep there the id of each element like [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4ee0nk/)

Comment: It still doesn't output it as "1-4 of 12" though

Comment: I've amended the original question to have a target div for where the "1-4 of 12" output should display (div id="counter")

Comment: So nearly almost there... it works straight off page load, but it doesn't work dynamically with the carousel. http://jsfiddle.net/8synkduL/ - use the prev/next links and you'll see what I mean. Had a bit of a play with the script but can't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes because you have to update values when carousel triggers.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just a prototype for a UX project - I'm not a full developer so not sure how to do this when the carousel triggers? I've updated the jsfiddle with my own attempt but isn't working